# Method to parse HTML document in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, html-parser

like DOMDocument class in PHP, is there any class in RUBY (i.e the core RUBY), to parse and get node elements value from a HTML Document.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is no built-in HTML parser (yet), but some very good ones are available, in particular [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Meta-answer: For common needs like these, I'd recommend checking out the [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com) site. You'll notice that Nokogiri is the top recommendation for [HTML parsers](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing.html)

Answer (score 9):

You should check out [hpricot](http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot). It's exceedingly good. It's not 'core' ruby, but it's a commonly used gem.

Comment: Hpricot sadly is no more. Nokogiri is now the preferred solution.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby Cheerio - A jQuery style HTML parser in ruby. A most simplified version of Nokogiri for crawlers. This is the ruby version of most popular NodeJS package **cheerio**.

[Follow the link for a simple crawler example.](https://github.com/dineshsprabu/ruby-cheerio/blob/master/sample_code/get_gem_info.rb)

**gem install ruby-cheerio**

```
require 'ruby-cheerio'

jQuery = RubyCheerio.new("<html><body><h1 class='one'>h1_1</h1><h1>h1_2</h1></body></html>")

jQuery.find('h1').each do |head_one|
    p head_one.text
end

# getting attribute values like jQuery.
p jQuery.find('h1.one')[0].prop('h1','class')

# function chaining similar to jQuery.
p jQuery.find('body').find('h1').first.text
```

Comment: Very good approach! Nice recommendation! Thanks @dineshsprabu.

Comment: Thanks  Fernando Kosh

Answer (score 5):

You can also try **Oga** by Yorick Peterse.

It is an XML/HTML parser written in Ruby that does not require system libraries such as libxml. You can find it here. https://github.com/YorickPeterse/oga