# Parse XHTML using Ruby

Tags: ruby, xhtml

Is there any way I can parse a remote html page, in Ruby, preferably using jQuery like selectors?

For example, I could select all the div having a specific class, and get the content of all those elements in an array.

I was trying to use Regex for this, but I think using XML parser would be better.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554909/method-to-parse-html-document-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

I found [hpricot](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot) is very similar.