# Regular Expression to extract (video) names from html tags

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have a webpage which contains the followsing code snippet containg links to videos:

```
<a href="video.php?video=sampel1.mov">
<a href="video.php?video=anothersample.mov">
<a href="video.php?video=yetanothersample.mov">
```

I want to use sed and regular expression to extract the video names, eg:

```
sampel1.mov 
anothersample.mov 
yetanothersample.mov
```

so I can use `wget` to download them.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you want something like clive instead.

Comment: It turns out `grep` is best for this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed -n 's/.*video=\([^"]*\)">/\1/p' inputfile
```

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po '(?<=video=).*?(?=">)' inputfile
```

Pipe either of those commands through `xargs`:

```
command | xargs wget ...
```

Comment: What if I want to get result for wget to use immediately? I mean dont put the result in a file.

Comment: @DocWiki: I made the `sed` command print selectively and added a `grep` command which works the same way. Either can be piped through `xargs` to pass to `wget`. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Thanks a lot. still there is a problem: Kevin Ballard's method will work even if the following three lines become one:<a href="video.php?video=sampel1.mov"><a href="video.php?video=anothersample.mov"><a href="video.php?video=yetanothersample.mov"> But your sed method wont work, I guess sed is working line by line.

Comment: @DocWiki: The `grep` command will work in that case. This is why bta's answer discusses using a proper parsing tool for this type of file. Using regexes for this [leads to madness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Hi, Dennis, Maybe I am asking too much. But can you explain a little bit about your `grep -Po '(?<=video=).*?(?=">)'`. It works perfectly. I googled and still dont understand it very well. what does the `()` and `?` mean there? Thanks!

Comment: @DocWiki: The `-P` options enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions and the `-o` option causes only the matched portion to be output. The `(?...)` patterns are lookarounds (look behind and look ahead). They match the regex within, but do not include it in the result. See [`man pcrepattern`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcrepattern).

Comment: @Dennis You are so knowledgeable. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple like

```
grep -o 'video.php?video=[^"]\+' | sed -e 's/^video.php?video=//'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to retrieve your movie names.

Create a file, for eg. **movie_string.txt** with all your strings containing the movie name

Now, create a sed script file, say **movie_name.sed** with the following:

`s/\"//g`
`s/<//g`
`s/>//g`
`s/\(.*=\)\([a-z]\)/ \2/`

save and quit.

Now from the terminal, you just need to issue the following command to redirect the result to another file **movie.txt**:

```
sed -f movie_name.sed movie_string.txt > movie.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning: parsing HTML/XML using regular expressions is usually [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335250/parsing-xml-with-regex-in-java/335446#335446).  Instead, use a language like Ruby or Python that has an XML parser library that can intelligently interpret the page structure.

Here are a few questions that might help you out (many more are only a quick search away):

- [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautiful-soup)
- [What's the easiest way to extract the links on a web page using python without BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414375/whats-the-easiest-way-to-extract-the-links-on-a-web-page-using-python-without-be)
- [Parse XHTML using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722443/parse-xhtml-using-ruby)

**Update:**

In your comment, you mentioned that you already know how to do the link extraction in Python but that you don't want to use a Python script that invokes `wget` directly.  You can still solve this with Python (which is probably the easiest solution since you already know how to do it).  If your Python script prints the extracted filenames to standard output with a newline following each name, you can use either of the following shell commands to do what you want to do:

```
python your_script.py >filenames.txt
wget -i filenames.txt
```

or

```
python your_script.py | wget -i -
```

This will pass the data extracted by your script to `wget` without requiring your script to invoke `wget` via a system call.

Comment: Dead wrong in this case: XML/HTML are nearly impossible to parse with regex because of the fact that nesting tags makes it context free. It's like dealing with balanced parentheses-- of course that's going to be hard with regex. However, in this case only opening `<a>` tags are being examined, so regular expressions are completely suitable for this task. (-1)

Comment: I'll admit that if the `<a>` tags don't follow a regular pattern (e.g., if there's a "title" attribute before the "href" in some of them, but not in others), it gets more difficult. But the fact remains, as long as you're studying strictly open tags of a certain type, you're far more likely to be dealing with a regular language and the knee-jerk "oh noes never parse HTML with regex" cries just make you look silly.

Comment: @Platinum Azure- I'm mainly speaking from bad personal experiences here.  I've tried to do something similar, only to be bitten by numerous problems like unwanted links inside HTML comments, `<a>` tags that span multiple lines, and multiple `<a>` tags in the same line.  Given how easy it is to parse using an intelligent XML parser, there's really not much reason to muck about with regular expressions in the first place.  It might work for this one example, but it's better to have something that works for any given page.

Comment: thanks. I know how to do this in Python. But I have to use wget later. so Python is not a good option.

Comment: @DocWiki- How does that make Python a bad option?  You can run a `wget` command from Python, you can write the list of files to a .txt file and feed that into `wget` as input (use `wget -i filename.txt`), or you can send the list of files to standard output and pipe that into `wget -i -`.

Comment: @bta Thanks a lot. But I think running `wget` inside Python is dangerous. It uses something called system call. Sounds dangerous to me.

Comment: @DocWiki- A system call is not dangerous, it's simply a Python script launching another program (no different than a shell script launching a program).  As I mentioned above, you have other options available that don't involve Python invoking `wget` directly.  I'll edit my question to give an example.

Comment: @DocWiki: A system call is only dangerous if the system call (a) has the ability to do major damage to your system, and (b) is performed with user input that you haven't validated. So, for example, if you called `'rm %s' % someUserInput`, and the user input was `"-rf /"`, you're obviously in trouble! But `wget` just fetches web content and stores it to a directory to which you would normally have write-access. Not at all harmful.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat yourlinks.txt | cut -f2 -d\" | cut -f2 -d=
```

Comment: I'll never be an emo vampire.